# Elasticsearch gives different scores as documents increase

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

have a good day

I have two product lists that are very large and will be constantly growing, and I want their titles to be compared. That is, I compare the first product from the first list with all the products from the second list and proceed in the same way, and those that are similar are placed in the same group.

I wrote my code with Laravel and Elastic and my working method is as follows.

I indexed the second list in Elastic and I do foreach on the first list and they are compared with the second list by Elastic. Finally, I use min_score and  I find that those that were higher than a certain score are acceptable .

But the above method works for a list with a fixed number, and if the number of the second list (the list indexed in Elastic) increases, the score values ​​change.
For example, it found product "a" and gave it a score of 10. When the second list increases, he finds the same product "a" but gives it a score of, for example, 12.

I saw two solutions, one is to use "function_score", which seems useless, or to change the similarity algorithm and change it from "BM25" to "boolean".

Is there another way to receive the similar scores for the found products, no matter how many products I change?

Answer (score 0):

No, not as long as you rely on Elasticsearch's scoring which is tf/idf based (BM25 actually). This score is influenced by the number of documents you have, the amount of text indexed, words frequency and distribution, the number of shards and replicas in the system, and the segment merging status. It is to be expected that scores will change from query to query - especially as documents change in the index (increase or decrease).